# Why file isnt uploading in the directory?

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files to the directory but I keep getting error or console

```
GET http://localhost:9999/store/uploads/.jgp
```

Whilst my html is

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="formSettingStoreLogo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <p>Put a logo </p>
                <br />
                <input type="file" name="logo" />
                <input type="submit" name="submitLogo" id="submitLogo" value="Upload" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

And code of php is

```
$target_dir = "../uploads/store/logo/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "\n"."The file ". basename( $_FILES["logo"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

For further information

My script for uploading images is at

```
C:/wamp64/www/store/settingstore.php
```

And the location I want to upload photos are

```
C:/wamp64/www/uploads/store/logo
```

Comment: should be `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"]...`

Comment: Still getting the exact same error :\

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Yeah its fixed!

Comment: @Alexis Can you please add the error you saw and also describe how you fixed this for future reference? Finding the exact same issue with "It's fixed!" note and no solution can be frustrating for other programmers.

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"] ... I forgot to ctrl + s